# SQL JOB retry interval to 15 minutes

Tags: sql-job

I have one sql job with settings as below

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
@job_id = @jobId, 
@name = N'MY TestJOB', 
@enabled = 1, 
@freq_type = 4, 
@freq_interval = 1, 
@freq_subday_type = 1, 
@freq_subday_interval = 0, 
@freq_relative_interval = 0, 
@freq_recurrence_factor = 0, 
@active_start_date = 20200611,
@active_start_time = 063000,  
@active_end_date = 99991231,
@active_end_time = 235959
```

want's to change it so that it can be retry every 15 minutes

I am thinking of changing it like

```
 EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
@job_id = @jobId, 
@name = N'MY TestJOB', 
@enabled = 1, 
@freq_type = 4, 
@freq_interval = 1, 
@freq_subday_type = 4, 
@freq_subday_interval = 15, 
@freq_relative_interval = 0, 
@freq_recurrence_factor = 0, 
@active_start_date = 20200611,
@active_start_time = 063000,  
@active_end_date = 99991231,
@active_end_time = 235959
```